# Where does the ConcurrentModificationException occur?

Tags: android, list, dictionary, concurrentmodification

I occassionally(random) get a `ConcurrentModificationException` in my app with the following exception message:

```
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:62)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterat
```

My code is relatively large and Lists/Maps all used in different places. The exception message doesn't tell where the exception is occuring. How can i find out where the exception occurs so i can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

After getting each item from Iterator remove it from the Iterator .

```
iterator.remove();
```

It will avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: I don't know what code to post because the exception message doesn't tell where the exception occurs. I can't post all the code for different reasons.